# php - Simple Blog Script - Redirecting to a page with given content

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm building a blog and I'm done with the webpage which shows all the posts with their titles, pictures and short descriptions (each post = one picture, one title and one description). Next I want to enable redirecting users to a page with a full post after clicking a chosen title, but I don't know where to start.

**`home.php`**

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('connection.php');

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_post = "SELECT postID, title, date, category, description, pimage, text FROM post";
$post = mysql_query($query_post, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post);
$totalRows_post = mysql_num_rows($post);

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_joining = "SELECT * FROM image inner join post on post.pimage = image.imagename";
$joining = mysql_query($query_joining, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining);
$totalRows_joining = mysql_num_rows($joining);
?>


<ul>
<?php
while($row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining)) {     
?>
  <li>
   <a href="post.php"><img src="images/<?php echo $row_joining['imagename']; ?>"></a>
   <h3><a href="post.php"><?php echo $row_joining['title']; ?></a></h3>
   <p><?php echo $row_joining['description']; ?></p>
   <a href="post.php">Read more</a>
  </li>
<?php
}
?>   
</ul>
```

**`post.php`**

```
<div>
  <h1><?php echo $row_post['title']; ?></h1>
  <img "images/<?php echo $row_post['pimage']; ?>">
  <h4><?php echo $row_post['date']; ?>, <?php echo $row_post['category']; ?></h4>
  <p><?php echo $row_post['text']; ?></p>
</div>
```

I know that especially the `post.php` needs changes, but I don't know how to proceed so that the chosen post will be displayed in `post.php`.

Comment: mysql [is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you showing all posts, in the href you can put like this:

```
<a href="post.php?post='.$row_post['postID'].'">
```

Then in post.php you can do something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['post']))
{
   // check if post is integer
   // check if post exist in database
   // show content from that post only. WHERE postID = data

}
   else
   {
      // list all posts.
   }
```